# Is there a decent HTML-table-generator class in PHP?

Tags: php, html, html-table

I'm looking for a decent class in PHP which will generate complex HTML tables, i.e. it should support colspan/rowspan and individual CSS classes for rows, columns and cells.

Comment: Removed my answer since you did not like it, hope you find something you like!

Comment: I just wrote this one: https://github.com/donquixote/cellbrush

Answer (score 3):

It seems like your question is pretty closely related to a little project I'm working on.

To solve this problem, I wrote **htmlgen**, mirrored on [packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/z1ffy/htmlgen) -

```
use function htmlgen\html as h;
use function htmlgen\map;

$beeData = [
  'pop' => 'yup',
  'candy' => 'sometimes',
  'flowers' => 'so much',
  'water' => 'not really',
  'sand' => 'indifferent',
  'donuts' => 'most definitely'
];

echo h('table',
  h('thead',
    h('tr',
      h('td', 'item'),
      h('td', 'do bees like it?')
    )
  ),
  h('tbody',
    map($beeData, function($value, $key) { return
      h('tr',
        h('td', $key),
        h('td', $value)
      );
    })
  )
);
```

Output (whitespace not included in actual output)

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>item</td>
      <td>do bees like it?</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
     <td>pop</td>
     <td>yup</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>candy</td>
     <td>sometimes</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>flowers</td>
     <td>so much</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>water</td>
     <td>not really</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>sand</td>
     <td>indifferent</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>donuts</td>
     <td>most definitely</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Even though some of the examples seem like they might be somewhat verbose, I think the ability to utilize the DSL in a very programmatic way makes it very powerful.

If you are actually interested in creating your own library, I'd love to collaborate with you. Please check out the project and let me know what you think :)

Comment: The `<tr class="header">` is semantically clumsy, you should use `<thead>` and `<tbody>` instead.

Comment: @Artefact2, I understand `<thead>` is more semantically correct. I was just making a simple example here :)

Comment: Looks very close to `DOMDocument` stuff. Why not use this one directly? :)

Comment: @kaiser, this is an _extremely_ old post. For what it's worth, I wanted something a little more intuitive than `DOMDocument`. Then about 10 minutes later, I wanted something more intuitive than PHP.

Comment: Hehe... And yeah, I didn't check the date.